# Struggling with left join

Tags: sql, left-join

I'm struggling with left joining the earliest row in this left join.

The results are showing a 2011 date, but i know for a fact this particular row should be returning 2008.

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 
   f.name as [Franchisee]
  ,p.paid_date as paid_date
 FROM franchisees_franchisee f
 OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                FROM   era_project_invoice_payment p
                WHERE  f.franchiseeid = p.franchiseeid
                and    p.deleted = 0 and p.payment_confirmed = 1
                ORDER  BY p.eraprojectinvoicepaymentid ASC) p
where 
f.deleted = 0
and f.name LIKE '%VKlinkosch%'
```

Below returns the correct, 2008 date.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
   f.name as [Franchisee]
  ,min(p.paid_date) as paid_date
 from [era_uat_shared].[dbo].[franchisees_franchisee] f
left join era_project_invoice_payment p
on f.franchiseeid = p.franchiseeid
where f.deleted = 0
and f.name LIKE '%VKlinkosch%'
GROUP BY f.name
```

Problem is, I need more than just the Paid Date from the payments table! :(

Comment: I would double check your facts... Either the 2008 date isn't for that `franchseeid`, or `deleted` does not equal `0`, or the `payment_confirmed` does not equal `1`.

Comment: Perhaps it isn't ordering as you're expecting in the inner view?

Comment: Hi Zim, The 2008 refers to the paid date. To get this 2008 date, all I had to do is use min(paid_date) and the f.name field in a tiny query.

Comment: are you looking for the min or max paid date per franchisee?

Comment: I'm looking for the min row, by paid date where the franchiseeid matches in both tables.

Comment: @Justin see answer, it allows multiple fields to be returned

Comment: Column 'era_project_invoice_payment.paid_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136484/discussion-between-user1327961-and-justin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    f.name as [Franchisee]
    , p.*
FROM        franchisees_franchisee  f
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY franchiseeid ORDER BY paid_date ASC) rn
        , p.*
    FROM
        era_project_invoice_payment p
    WHERE
        deleted = 0
        AND payment_confirmed = 1
)                                   p
ON 
    f.franchiseeid = p.franchiseeid
    AND f.deleted = 0
    AND f.name LIKE '%VKlinkosch%'
    AND p.rn = 1
```

Comment: This guy is a boss. :)